# Creating a Combine's publisher like RxSwift's Observable.Create for an Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift, combine

I use the following piece of code to generate a cold `RxSwift Observable`:

```
func doRequest<T :Mappable>(request:URLRequestConvertible) -> Observable<T> {
        let observable = Observable<T>.create { [weak self] observer in
        guard let self = self else { return Disposables.create() }
        self.session.request(request).validate().responseObject { (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
            switch response.result {
                case .success(let obj):
                    observer.onNext(obj)
                    observer.onCompleted()
                case .failure(let error):
                    let theError = error as Error
                    observer.onError(theError)
            }
        }
         return Disposables.create()
    }
    return observable
}
```

where `Mappable` is an [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper) based type, and `self.session` is an Alamofire's `Session` object.

I can't find an equivalent to `Observable.create {...}` in Apple's `Combine` framework. What I only found is `URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for:)` which creates a publisher using Apple's `URLSession` class.

How can I convert the above observable to an Alamofire Combine's publisher ?

**EDIT**:
using the solution provided by rob, I ended up with the following:

```
 private let apiQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "API", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

  func doRequest<T>(request: URLRequestConvertible) -> AnyPublisher<T, AFError> where T : Mappable {

       Deferred { [weak self] () -> Future<T, AFError> in

          guard let self = self else {
              return Future<T, AFError> { promise in  
promise(.failure(.explicitlyCancelled))  }
        }

          return Future { promise in
            self.session
            .request(request)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
                promise(response.result)
            }
        }
    }
    .handleEvents(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        if case .failure (let error) = completion {
                //handle the error
        }
    })
    .receive(on: self.apiQueue)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

**EDIT2:** I have to remove the private queue since it's not needed, Alamofire does the parsing the decoding on its own, so remove the queue and its usages (`.receive(on: self.apiQueue)`)

Comment: Note that Alamofire is already performing the response handling in a background queue, with the completion handlers called on the main queue (which is only completing the `Future`, so you probably don't need your `receive(on:)` call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Future`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/future) to connect `responseObject`'s callback to a Combine `Publisher`. I don't have Alamofire handy for testing, but I think the following should work:

```
func doRequest<T: Mappable>(request: URLRequestConvertible) -> AnyPublisher<T, AFError> {
    return Future { promise in
        self.session
            .request(request)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
            promise(response.result)
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note that this is somewhat simpler than the RxSwift version because `promise` takes a `Result` directly, so we don't have to switch over `response.result`.

A `Future` is sort of a “lukewarm” publisher. It is like a hot observable because it executes its body immediately and only once, so it starts the Alamofire request immediately. It is also like a cold observable, because every subscriber eventually receives a value or an error (assuming you eventually call `promise`). The `Future` only executes its body once, but it caches the `Result` you pass to `promise`.

You can create a truly cold publisher by wrapping the `Future` in a [`Deferred`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/deferred):

```
func doRequest<T: Mappable>(request: URLRequestConvertible) -> AnyPublisher<T, AFError> {
    return Deferred {
        Future { promise in
            self.session
                .request(request)
                .validate()
                .responseObject { (response: AFDataResponse<T>) in
                    promise(response.result) }
        }
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

`Deferred` calls its body to create a new inner `Publisher` every time you subscribe to it. So each time you subscribe, you'll create a new `Future` that will immediately start a new Alamofire request. This is useful if you want to use the `retry` operator, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59224781/77567).

Comment: I have added an Edit in my question

Comment: Do you need more help? I don’t see any requests for more help in your edit.

Comment: yeah, I'm skeptic about where to place the call to `receive(on:)` operator, thought would be bette to place it right after the `Future` rather than after `Deferred`?

Comment: It’s fine where you have it, but I don’t know why you need to dispatch to a private queue.

Comment: excerpt from page 248 of Ray Wenderlich's Combine book: "... to parse JSON on a background thread and keep the rest of the app responsive, let‘s create a new custom dispatch queue....", then the author creates the queue I've listed in the question. Usage as listed in the book: `URLSession.shared
.dataTaskPublisher(for: url) .receive(on: apiQueue)
.map(\.data)
.decode(type: MyModel.self, decoder: decoder) .catch { _ in Empty<MyModel, Error>() } .eraseToAnyPublisher()`

Comment: I thought at first that I have to use `.subscribe(on:)` instead of `receive(on:)` to process fetching and parsing the json on a background queue, but as I understand, most uses of `.subscribe(on:)` would be in case of a custom (heavy) subscription you create in which case it's much better to separate that workload into a background queue when you subscribe to the (custom) publisher that leverages this subscription.

Comment: The parsing in your example is, I believe, done by Alamofire before you hand the result off to Combine. So you need to use an Alamofire API to decode on a background queue (if it doesn’t do so by default).

Comment: that's totally right, Alamofire does indeed parse and decode by default, so I guess no need for the private background queue.

Comment: That `Deferred` publisher sometimes loses value and completes, I opened a question for this problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60223041/combine-publisher-sometimes-loses-value-and-completes?noredirect=1#comment106523639_60223041

Comment: Just a remark: Even though this approach is perfectly fine for the given example, it technically creates a special type of an `Publisher`, i.e. the Combine version of an RxSwift `Single` (according to https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/Documentation/Traits.md#single "A Single is a variation of Observable that, instead of emitting a series of elements, is always guaranteed to emit either a single element or an error."). So I'd be interested if there's also a way to create the Combine version of a general Observable (being capable of emitting multiple events, not just one).