# Combine: Publisher sometimes loses value and completes

Tags: ios, swiftui, combine

I have a simple `Deferred Publisher` that reads data from disk and I display the data in a `SwiftUI List`, the `Publisher` works well most of the time, but ***sometimes*** it doesn't behave well, it just loses its value (which's an array of `Model` objects) and completes with `finished` message. I've tried a workaround mentioned [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-receive-on-runloop-main-loses-sent-value-how-can-i-make-it-work/28631/5) to use the `buffer` operator to keep the value in buffer because I believe the `Combine's Publisher` by design won't pass the data downstream if there is no demand requested by subscribers and hence dropping this data and completes, however using `buffer` didn't solve the issue.

The code I have:

```
enum FileError: Error {
    case someError
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var modelArray = [Model]()
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func readData() {
        DataSource()
            .readFromBundle(resource: "Sample", type: "json")
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("Completion: \(completion)")
            }) { array in
                self.modelArray = array
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.viewModel.modelArray) { model in
                Text("\(model.name)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.readData()
        }
    }
}

struct Model: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

class DataSource {
    private let readQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ReadQueue", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

    func readFromBundle (resource: String, type:String) -> AnyPublisher<[Model], FileError> {
            Deferred {
                 Future { promise in
                    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "json"),
                      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
                      let modelArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
                      else {
                        promise(.failure(.someError))
                        return
                    }
                      promise(.success(modelArray))
                }
            }
           .receive(on: self.readQueue)
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
}
```

[This is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vuit169xl8gspq/Test.zip?dl=0) to download a working sample project.

**EDIT:**

Environment: Xcode 11.3.1, iOS 13.3 iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator and device.

gif screenshot (notice the console output)

[image]

***EDIT2:***

if I add any downstream publishers, like `combineLatest` for example just before `sink` in the consumer function `readData()` then a new behavior introduced, which's chaining an async publisher (readFromBundle) with a sync publisher (`combineLatest`) will result in the value will not deliver at all on `iOS 13.3+` devices and will sometimes deliver on devices below `iOS 13.3`, as stated on [this link](https://forums.swift.org/t/combine-receive-on-runloop-main-loses-sent-value-how-can-i-make-it-work/28631/39).

Comment: does the error occur in your linked project? i started it several times and it worked...

Comment: It’s not an error, it just doesn’t display the data because the publisher finishes, and yes it happens in the linked project but not always (90% of tries are success with data)

Comment: yeah, that*s what i meant...but never happened when i started it...

Comment: maybe you should give "real" ids...because yours are double 1...5

Comment: what ios version are u testing? i even tried it now with a repeating timer, it worked every time on ios 13.2

Comment: I have added a screenshot for the problem, and it's nothing to do with the IDs 'coz I fixed them now to be unique but nothing changed, when I run the project the publisher now usually drops the value at first run, and publishes it the second run, tried it multiple subsequent times it succeeds with value and sometimes finishes without a value.

Comment: with the IDs...this was just an idea...i  believe that this is not the reason -> check my "answer" it is not the answer, but for better readability i wrote it in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like racing-kind issue, please try the following (just by code-reading)

1) use background queue explicitly

```
private let readQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ReadQueue", qos: .background, 
    attributes: .concurrent)
```

2) schedule Publisher on this queue instead of receiving on it

```
.subscribe(on: self.readQueue)
```

Comment: scheduling instead of receiving did the trick, but couldn't understand why. now it behaves well and there is no single try in which it finishes without a value.

Answer (score 2):

Let see the documentation about `.receive(on:)`

Specifies the scheduler on which to receive elements from the publisher.
Declaration

```
func receive<S>(on scheduler: S, options: S.SchedulerOptions? = nil) -> Publishers.ReceiveOn<Publishers.SubscribeOn<Deferred<Future<[Model], FileError>>, DispatchQueue>, S> where S : Scheduler
```

Discussion

You use the `receive(on:options:)` operator to receive results on a specific scheduler, such as performing UI work on the main run loop. In contrast with `subscribe(on:options:)`, which affects upstream messages, `receive(on:options:)` changes the execution context of downstream messages. In the following example, requests to jsonPublisher are performed on backgroundQueue, but elements received from it are performed on RunLoop.main.

```
let jsonPublisher = MyJSONLoaderPublisher() // Some publisher.
let labelUpdater = MyLabelUpdateSubscriber() // Some subscriber that updates the UI.

jsonPublisher
    .subscribe(on: backgroundQueue)
    .receiveOn(on: RunLoop.main)
    .subscribe(labelUpdater)
```

Parameters

scheduler
The scheduler the publisher is to use for element delivery.
options 
Scheduler options that customize the element delivery.
Returns

A publisher that delivers elements using the specified scheduler.

in your case it means

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum FileError: Error {
    case someError
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var modelArray = [Model]()
    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    func readData() {
        DataSource()
            .readFromBundle(resource: "Sample", type: "json")
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("Completion: \(completion)")
            }) { array in
                print("received value")
                self.modelArray = array
        }.store(in: &subscriptions)
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.viewModel.modelArray) { model in
                Text("\(model.name)")
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.viewModel.readData()
        }
    }
}

struct Model: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

class DataSource {
    private let readQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ReadQueue", qos: .default, attributes: .concurrent)

    func readFromBundle (resource: String, type:String) -> AnyPublisher<[Model], FileError> {
            Deferred {
                 Future { promise in
                    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "json"),
                      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
                      let modelArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Model].self, from: data)
                      else {
                        promise(.failure(.someError))
                        return
                    }
                      promise(.success(modelArray))
                }
            }
            .subscribe(on: readQueue)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
           .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
}
```

which explain, why Asperi's solution works. The difference is, that there is not necessary to call .receive(on:) again in `readData()`

the difference between `DispatchQueue.main` and `RunLoop.main` are not significant in your example.

Answer (score 0):

the first run does not fail, it just "needs" a time to load it....you can check this by adding this.

```
print("ready")
promise(.success(modelArray))
```

and then set a breakpoint to "not loaded yet" and you will see that the "not loaded yet" appears before the "ready" is printed in the console. This is not a drop of the publisher.

As onAppear() says, it will be called after the UI was shown....

```
if self.viewModel.modelArray.count == 0 {
                Text("not loaded yet")
            } else {
                List(self.viewModel.modelArray) { model in
                    Text("\(model.name)")
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is that the `readQueue` that is used in `receive(on:)` is concurrent. Both the value and the completion are dispatched to this queue separately, such that the order of value and completion are not guaranteed. If a downstream subscriber receives the completion first, it will cancel its subscription and ignore the value. Making the `readQueue` serial works just as well as using another serial queue such as `DispatchQueue.main` directly.

Using `subscribe(on:)` instead of `receive(on:)` worked in combination with the concurrent queue, because the `promise` call causes the value and completion sending to be dispatched together.