# Swift combine retry only for some error types

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a custom pipeline where I want to have 3 retry attempt for some error codes which are recoverable plus I want to add some short delay for the recoverable error. Anyone has an idea how I can do it?

```
func createRequest(for message: Message) -> AnyPublisher<ResponseMessage, Error> {
    Future<ResponseMessage, Error> { promise in
        .....   
    }
    .tryCatch({ error -> AnyPublisher<ResponseMessage, Error> in
        // If error is a recoverable error retry, otherwise fail directly
        if case let MessageBusError.messageError(responseError) = error {
            if responseError.isRecoverable {
                // Make a next attempt only for recoverable error
                throw error
            }
        }
            //Should fail directly if the error code is not recoverable
        return Fail<ResponseMessage, Error>(error: error)
               .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    })
    .retry(3)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Basically, you need a `retryIf` operator, so you can provide a closure to tell Combine which errors should be retried, and which not. I'm not aware of such an operator, but it's not hard to build one for yourself.

The idiomatic way is to extend the `Publishers` namespace with a new type for your operator, and then extend `Publisher` to add support for that operator so that yo can chain it along with other operators.

The implementation could look like this:

```swift
extension Publishers {
    struct RetryIf<P: Publisher>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = P.Output
        typealias Failure = P.Failure
        
        let publisher: P
        let times: Int
        let condition: (P.Failure) -> Bool
                
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Failure == S.Failure, Output == S.Input {
            guard times > 0 else { return publisher.receive(subscriber: subscriber) }
            
            publisher.catch { (error: P.Failure) -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> in
                if condition(error)  {
                    return RetryIf(publisher: publisher, times: times - 1, condition: condition).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                } else {
                    return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher()
                }
            }.receive(subscriber: subscriber)
        }
    }
}

extension Publisher {
    func retry(times: Int, if condition: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) -> Publishers.RetryIf<Self> {
        Publishers.RetryIf(publisher: self, times: times, condition: condition)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
func createRequest(for message: Message) -> AnyPublisher<ResponseMessage, Error> {
    Deferred {
        Future<ResponseMessage, Error> { promise in
            // future code
        }        
    }
    .retry(times: 3) { error in
        if case let MessageBusError.messageError(responseError) = error, responseError.isRecoverable {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Note that I wrapped your `Future` within a `Deferred` one, otherwise the `retry` operator would be meaningless, as the closure will not be executed multiple times. More details about that behaviour here: [Swift. Combine. Is there any way to call a publisher block more than once when retry?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59224781/1974224).

---

Alternatively, you can write the `Publisher` extension like this:

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func retry(_ times: Int, if condition: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) -> Publishers.RetryIf<Self> {
        Publishers.RetryIf(publisher: self, times: times, condition: condition)
    }
    
    func retry(_ times: Int, unless condition: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) -> Publishers.RetryIf<Self> {
        retry(times, if: { !condition($0) })
    }
}
```

, which enables some funky stuff, like this:

```swift
extension Error {
    var isRecoverable: Bool { ... }
    var isUnrecoverable: Bool { ... }
}

// retry at most 3 times while receiving recoverable errors
// bail out the first time when encountering an error that is
// not recoverable
somePublisher
    .retry(3, if: \.isRecoverable)

// retry at most 3 times, bail out the first time when
// an unrecoverable the error is encountered
somePublisher
    .retry(3, unless: \.isUnrecoverable)
```

Or even funkier, ruby-style:

```swift
extension Int {
    var times: Int { self }
}

somePublisher
    .retry(3.times, unless: \.isUnrecoverable)
```

Comment: This sounds to me to be the better approach. Thank you a lot.

Comment: How would you add a delay on retry?

Answer (score 7):

Typically, I try to avoid building new publishers, and instead prefer to compose publishers from built-in operators. I found it to be rather tricky to do here. Maybe someone can suggest a better approach.

`Retry` resubscribes on *any* failure, so to trick it, I packaged any *non-recoverable* errors into a [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) value containing the error, but leaving recoverable errors as failures to `.retry`; then eventually unpack the `Result` back into the corresponding value/error.

Here's how it would work in your case:

```
func createRequest(for message: Message)-> AnyPublisher<ResponseMessage, Error> {
    Future<ResponseMessage, Error> { promise in
        .....   
    }

    // pack a value into Result
    .map { v -> Result<ResponseMessage, Error> in .success(v) }
    .tryCatch { error -> AnyPublisher<Result<ResponseMessage, Error>, Error> in
        if case let MessageBusError.messageError(responseError) = error {
            if responseError.isRecoverable {
                // Keep recoverable errors as failures
                throw error
            }
        }
        // pack a non-recoverable error into Result with a failure   
        return Just(.failure(error)).setFailureType(Error.self)
                  .eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
    .retry(3)

    // unpack back
    .flatMap { result in result.publisher }

    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

For completeness, to extend `Publisher` with the above approach:

```
extension Publisher {
   private func retryOnly<U: Publisher>(
         upstream: U, 
         retries: Int, 
         when predicate: @escaping (U.Failure) -> Bool
      ) -> AnyPublisher<U.Output, U.Failure> {

      upstream
         .map { v -> Result<U.Output, U.Failure> in .success(v) }
         .catch { err -> AnyPublisher<Result<U.Output, U.Failure>, U.Failure> in
            if predicate(err) {
               return Fail(error: err).eraseToAnyPublisher()
            } else {
               return Just(.failure(err))
                  .setFailureType(to: U.Failure.self)
                  .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
         }
         .retry(retries)
         .flatMap { result in result.publisher }
         .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
    
   func retry(_ retries: Int, when predicate: @escaping (Failure) -> Bool) 
        -> AnyPublisher<Output, Failure> {

      return retryOnly(upstream: self, retries: retries, when: predicate)
   }
}
```

```
failingPublisher.retry(3, when: { $0 is RecoverableError })
```

Comment: Instead of using a `Just` publisher and the `setFailureType` operator, use a `Result.Publisher`. You can specify a failure type for the latter.

Comment: @PeterSchorn, not sure I follow. How would that work?

Comment: replace `Just(.failure(err)).setFailureType(to: U.Failure.self)` with `Result.Publisher(.success(.failure(err)))`

Comment: @PeterSchorn, ah, I see. Yeah, that could work too. But why do you think it's better other than being somewhat shorter? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference honestly.